# python - how to run simple script via web instead of a executable file

Tags: python

I am trying to have someone without Python installed use a simple program.

Have compiled it using *py2exe,* it worked, but it requires too much additional files. Have tried *PyInstaller,* but getting some errors when generating the executable file.

Anyway, I was thinking that it would be better upload that program to somewhere in the web, so, anyone with the link could use it in a much easier and practical way.

Does anyone know how I could accomplish that ?

Comment: Well, you could start by hooking it up to [WSGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Server_Gateway_Interface), I suppose.

Comment: What does the program do ? Does it recquire any file or extra data ?

Comment: Thank you Kevin, will have a look on the WSGI.

Comment: Math, thank you ! That is a program to create a simple file based in a file provided. I can either modify the program to ask the user to input the full file and then the simple file will be generated or use grab this from a specific folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you want someone to download your file, use command:

   ```
   python -m SimpleHTTPServer
   ```

   on your file dir. And the someone use url {YourIp}:8000 with browser to access download.
2. If you want to execute something in python script, create a small web service use flask:

   ```
   from flask import Flask
   app = Flask(__name__)

   @app.route('/')
   def hello_world():
       # Do your python script here
       return 'Hello World!'

   if __name__ == '__main__':
       app.run()
   ```

   And also, the someone can execute your script use {YourIp}:8000 with browser.

Except for the code, all you need is a server and a browser to access.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how simple it is you could send them the file and run using an online interpreter such as http://repl.it/languages/Python3